# Error HRESULT E_FAIL during completing Server Certificate Request in Server 2008R2

Tags: ssl-certificate, windows-server-2008-r2

I have no idea how to sort this as pictures when I was trying to complete the Server Certificate Request in Server 2008R2. And "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component" pop up. Please kindly help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E30Tw.jpg)